# File Date Format Changes When File is Sent to a Different System

Tags: excel, excel-formula

## #system-1#

### file1.xls

11/04/2018
12/04/2018
13/04/2018
14/04/2018
15/04/2018

## #Sytem-2#

### file1.xls

04-11-2018
  04-12-2018
  04-13-2018
  14/04/2018
  15/04/2018

I tried to change the format to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format takes the values from Region and Language in Windows (ignore the orange squares):

[image]

Switching between systems, you have two options:

- With formula:

  `=TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy")`
- With apostroph:

  Add `'` in front of the date, to convert it to text.

Comment: Thank You for Reply. But Region English(INDIA) There is no short date like 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Comment: @Rahul - change the formula to `=Text(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy")`. The red squares are from another screenshot, ignore them.

Comment: I tried with above formula Its Working fine. Thank you